# Spring boot ws starter changed default liquibase resource location

Tags: spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I have in my maven pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

which works fine, but once added:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

file, the project starts throw exception about

```
Cannot find changelog location: ServletContext resource [/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml] (please add changelog or check your Liquibase configuration)
```

Doing a bit of digging myself, I can see that after adding the start-ws dependency, the resource loading path at

```
@PostConstruct
    public void checkChangelogExists() {
        if (this.properties.isCheckChangeLogLocation()) {
            Resource resource = this.resourceLoader
                    .getResource(this.properties.getChangeLog());
            Assert.state(resource.exists(),
                    "Cannot find changelog location: " + resource
                            + " (please add changelog or check your Liquibase "
                            + "configuration)");
        }
        ServiceLocator serviceLocator = ServiceLocator.getInstance();
        serviceLocator.addPackageToScan(
                CommonsLoggingLiquibaseLogger.class.getPackage().getName());
    }
```

changed from

```
db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

to

```
/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

which is causing the issue, can anyone suggest why this behaviour occurs or just how to fix it? thanks!

Comment: What version of Spring Boot and which embedded servlet container are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.2.7.RELEASE, the embedded servlet is h2 (1.4.190) database as "jdbc:h2:mem:h2memdb"